# Profiling slow Zend Framework MVC setup

Tags: php, zend-framework, profiling

I am struggling with poor performance in Zend MVC.

I set up a single controller, which only does `die()`, and I enabled xdebug, and pulled up webgrind on my request which tells me:

```
789 different functions called in 2150 milliseconds (1 runs, 137 shown)
```

I am having problems determining exactly what is taking so long:

```
[procedural]      {main}    O   1   9   2150
[class]       Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap  O   5   7   1203
[class]       Zend_Config_Ini->_processKey  O   622     451     1191
[class]       Zend_Config_Ini->_processSection  O   2   49  1023
[class]       Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource    O   16  11  1017
```

(The above pretty much tells me it's the bootstrap firing up classes defined in my application.ini - but I have no idea which ones are slow)

What's a good way to pinpoint exactly what step in the code which is taking the bulk of the processing time?

Comment: *(tip)* [Zend Framework Performance Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.html)

Comment: @Gordon That's heavily outdated in places - Much of that isn't really even very effective. Some even make for worse performance.

Comment: @Jani no offense, but if i have the choice between someone claiming something without proof and an official reference guide, i'll stick with the official reference guide. I had good results with the advice given there.

Comment: @Gordon very well - perhaps you were luckier with it than I was, since my comment is based on what my experience was with that guide :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to expand webgrind output to locate what is your slower function call. Alternatively you could use [function trace feature](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) of Xdebug during your profiling session to get more informations on your function calls.

Generally speaking you should use cache wherever is possible. Memcache is faster than APC as `Zend_Cache` backend, but you still need APC extension installed (even in development mode) to get a great speedup of your code. I've benchmarked its impact on Zend Framework Quick Start [on my blog](http://www.codewithstyle.eu/2009/12/14/migliorare-le-performance-del-proprio-sito-php-con-lestensione-apc/) (that post is in Italian, but benchmark data are in English) and the result is pretty impressive, a 3x speedup for the home page.

I've applied the cache idea also for the `Zend_Application` config file (which in your example take half of the profiling time). I discussed it [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Using-cache-for-application-config-file-tt3421394.html) with Matthew Weier O'Phinney, Zend Framework project leader. What I've done is to override the default `Zend_Application` [`_loadConfig`](https://github.com/fabn/zle/blob/develop/library/Zle/Application.php#L35) method with a custom one which caches the result of the parsed file. You can find my class which implement this strategy [here on github](https://github.com/fabn/zle/blob/develop/library/Zle/Application.php).

Comment: Function trace was what I was looking for! Also, your application.ini cache approach looks promising for my case :)

Answer (score 4):

After having stripped the `require_once` of the library as explained in the official performance guide, you should install an opcode cache, like Zend Server CE, APC, or eAccelerator, even on your dev machine.

Also, some resource plugins you may configure in your `application.ini` may require data caching in order to perform well, like Zend_Db, Zend_Loader, etc. (i won't explain the difference with opcode caching here)

Don't forget that in production you will (and i really hope so) use opcode and memory caching, so you need to benchmark in close conditions.

In development you will certainly define a cache the invalidates very fast, so always refresh your page at least two times in a row before looking at the ms.

And then you can start to worry about your "real" bottlenecks.

Ok that was about ZF bootstrap performance. But your question was about profiling code. I use non-free tools for it, but **Xdebug** combined with **Kcachegrind** does it also quite well: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: What tools are you using? I'm still looking for a good php profiler.

Comment: I profile with Zend Studio + Zend Debugger. My Zend Debugger is installed in Zend Server CE, but you can download and install it in any lamp stack of your choice. I've read somewhere that Zend Debugger works in PhpStorm too, but i don't know if it does profiling there too, not only debugging

Comment: But honestly, Xdebug + Kcachegrind does the job very well, i'm on a Zend Studio solution because of it's integration with my client's Zend Server Entreprise, and it's the only reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I currently use PhpStorm, but it doesn't have profiling support integrated ([not yet](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-312?projectKey=WI&query=profiler)).

Comment: I'm manly on phpstorm too, and as soon as the 3 is out, i won't have any reason left to keep juggling with ZS. Can't wait !

Comment: You're somewhat not addressing my question, I already use APC for opcode cache (in fact, my slow performance is with APC enabled), and a controller which does nothing but `die()` is hardly a relevant case where memcached for Zend_Db is relevant. Also, webgrind is actually based on Kcachegrind, so that doesn't really solve my issue.